# Adapt my js code to an input

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I have this javascript code that creates a slider:

http://jsfiddle.net/samccone/ZMkkd/

Now, i want to use this code on a checkbox input. the problem is that the code creates a child element that slides in it's parent using a css position, and an input cannot have a child.

My idea was to use background-position and just slide the background of the input from left to right using css instead of using real positioning.

How can I adapt this script? It is quite easy I think but after a couple of tries I just gave up, i'm not good enough :).

Thanks for your help,

Christopher

Comment: Maybe it's better to just use what you have, style it however you need to, and have the on/off state attached to the value of a hidden input?

Comment: The final code will be distributed so i want it to be perfect :)
That's why I prefer custom code to some messy "it works" code.

Comment: I will never answer a question that says: "Can anyone adapt this script for me?". I will gladly answer questions, but not do work for you!

Comment: edited my question. :p. Anyway, I think doing the work for someone is only bad if that person has not put any effort in trying. AS i have tried for 1 hour to get this to work I think asking others for help is not inappropriate :).

Comment: that slider was fun.  I tried it again and again.  weeeeeee...

Comment: @pixelbobby hehe, yup agreed :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Believe it or not, for checkboxes a switch effect is possible to create without JavaScript.

If you follow your checkbox with a label:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="jim" />
<label for="jim"></label>
```

You will find that you can select the label with the next sibling selector:

```
input + label { /* some CSS */ }
```

Why is that useful? Because using the pseudo selector :checked you can now style the label based on the state of the checkbox:

```
input + label { background-position: 0 0; }
input:checked + label { background-position: 100% 0; }
```

Clearly, due to the for="jim" attribute, clicking on the label will change the state of the checkbox. So if you *hide* the checkbox, you end up with a styled, clickable label.

```
input { display: none; }
```

Of course, labels can have children so you can be as fancy as you want with your recreation of a switch. And you should be careful to include :focus styles as well, for people who tab to your checkbox rather than click on it.

For browsers that do not support the :checked pseudo class (IE8 and below), it's pretty easy to emulate with a global handler and a 'checked' class. Something like:

```
jQuery(document).bind('change', function(e){
  var elem = jQuery(e.target);

  // If this is not a checkox, do nothing.
  if (elem.attr('type') !== 'checkbox') { return; }

  // Add or remove checked class based on current state.
  if (elem.attr('checked')) { elem.removeClass('checked'); }
  else { elem.addClass('checked'); }
});
```

...should do it.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to store some data in object properties (or the `.data()` api), but your background position idea should work just fine. Just replace your calls to `.offset().left` with `.css('background-position')` (you'll have to `split` and `parseInt` the string it returns tho) and keep plugin' away at it.